# ActionScript Property - Public Getter, Protected Setter

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, compiler-errors

Is it possible to have a property with a public getter and protected setter?

I have the following code:

```
public class Mob extends Sprite {
    // snip

    private var _health:Number; // tried making this protected, didn't work
    public function get health():Number { return _health; }
    protected function set health(value:Number):void {
        _health = value;
    }

    // snip

    public function takeDamage(amount:Number, type:DamageType, ... additionalAmountAndTypePairs):void {
        var dmg:Number = 0;
        // snip
        var h:Number = this.health; // 1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property health through a reference with static type components.mobs:Mob.
        this.health = h - dmg; // 1059: Property is read-only.
    }
}
```

I did have `this.health -= dmg;` but I split it out to get more details on the compiler errors.

I don't understand how the property would be considered read-only within the same class. I also don't understand how it's inaccessible.

If I make the backing field, getter, and setter all protected, it compiles but it's not the result I want; I need health to be readable externally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, accessors have to have the same privilege levels as each other.  You can have your public
get set functions, then have a protected setHealth, getHealth function pair.  You could reverse it if you wish, but the key point is that you have one set of methods to access at a public privilege and another to access at a protected privilege level.

Comment: +1, After Googling around some more last night, I stumbled upon a similar answer with no workaround. I don't like the inconsistent API but I suppose I'll have to cope with the language's shortcomings.

Answer (score 3):

Since you will be updating `_health` from inside your `Mob` class only, you can write a private function for setting it.

```
private function setHealth(value:Number):void
{
    _health = value;
}
```

And keep the public getter as such.

Comment: +1, but accepted FlexFiend's answer because he pointed out that they _need_ to be the same privilege level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I think you may want to use

```
internal var _health:Number;
public function get health():Number { return _health; }
internal function set health(value:Number):void { _health = value; }
```

Comment: This causes an error when trying to set the health: `Versuchter Aufruf einer nicht verfügbaren Eigenschaft health über einen Verweis mit statischem Typ tmp:ModifierTest.`