# Actionscript: Accessing private setter in own constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, flex4, getter-setter

I am trying to set a variable whose setter is private in the constructor of the same class, but compiler keeps hitting me on the head with:

> 1059 Property is readonly
>   1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property gesamtBetrag through a
>   reference with static type ImmoObject.

```
package
{
    public class Huhu
    {
        private var _prop1:int;
        public function Huhu()
        {
            prop1 = 24;
        }

        public function get prop1():int
        {
            return _prop1;
        }

        private function set prop1(value:int):void
        {
            _prop1 = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Show the code.  Both the function and usage

Comment: have a look at the updated question please, I've added the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionScript Property - Public Getter, Protected Setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356977/actionscript-property-public-getter-protected-setter)

Comment: You can't mix and match public/private with a getter setter.    Why not just remove the setter and work with `_prop1` directly within this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, you cannot have a `private` setter and a `public` getter. The access modifier must be the same for getter and setter.

What you *can* do is only have a `public` getter and from within the class constructor or elsewhere you set the `private` variable directly:

```
class Foo {
    private var _prop:int;
    public function Foo() {
        _prop = 24;
    }
    public function get prop():int { return _prop; }
}
```

(Note that in this case you could actually just initialize the private variable with a value, ex `private _prop:int = 24`.)

You could also expose other means of changing the private variable, such as a function or a setter with a different name:

```
class Foo {
    private var _prop:int;
    public function get prop():int { return _prop; }
    protected function setProp(prop:int):void {
        _prop = prop;
    }
    protected function set propValue(value:int):int {
        _prop = value;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: To be clear, access types must match for getter/setters of *properties*, but you can mix private/public access of getter/setter *methods*, in similar style as Java:

```
private prop:int;
public getProp():int { return prop; }
private setProp(value:int):void {
    prop = value;
}
```

This is not as common of a style you see in AS3 because we have formal `get`/`set` property syntax, but it's still perfectly valid.

Comment: well that was what I was doing anyway. But it just feels so wrong! I come from Java world... Java has spoiled me :(

Comment: But in Java (last time I used it) there are no getter setter properties, only functions. You can make your functions in AS3 mixed private/public all you want, just like Java. It's only getter/setter *properties* that must have matching access types.

Comment: It might be worth adding that you can also mix implicit and explicit getter and setters with different access modifiers. In your last example, the getter could be "public get prop" while the setter is "private setProp". The advantage is that you can now add Bindable metadata to the getter and use it in binding statements.

Comment: Yep, that's the second example.

Answer (score 1):

Getter/setter must have the same signature or else they are simply not related. You have a public getter and a private setter, as a result they are not related and the public getter has no setter so it is read only.